# SQL -- return groups of records where one of the fields does not match amongst all records in the group

Tags: mysql, sql

In the sample table below, all records with the same `O_Id` should also have the same price. Obviously, for `O_Id`'s 1 and 3, not all records have the same price.

I'm having difficulty writing a query that would return all records from a table that have the same `O_Id` as one or more other records, but where the `OrderPrice` does not match among records with the same `O_id`.

**Sample table:**

```
+------+------------+------------+
| Type |  MySQL     | OrderPrice |
+======+============+============+
| 1    | 2008/11/12 | 1000       |
| 1    | 2008/10/23 | 2000       |
| 2    | 2008/09/02 |  700       |
| 2    | 2008/09/03 |  700       |
| 3    | 2008/08/30 | 2000       |
| 3    | 2008/10/04 | 2100       |
| 3    | 2008/08/30 | 2000       |
| 3    | 2008/10/04 | 2000       |
+------+------------+------------+
```

**Sample result set:**

```
+------+------------+------------+
| Type |  MySQL     | OrderPrice |
+======+============+============+
| 1    | 2008/11/12 | 1000       |
| 1    | 2008/10/23 | 2000       |
| 3    | 2008/08/30 | 2000       |
| 3    | 2008/10/04 | 2100       |
| 3    | 2008/08/30 | 2000       |
| 3    | 2008/10/04 | 2000       |
+------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `O_Id` where there are more than one different prices associated with:

```
SELECT O_Id
FROM myTable
GROUP BY O_Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OrderPrice) > 1
```

and use it as inner statement to get all rows for these `O_Id`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE O_Id IN (
    SELECT O_Id
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY O_Id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OrderPrice) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `Exists`:

```
Select * From OrderTable O
Where Exists(
    Select O_Id From OrderTable
    Where O_Id = O.O_Id
    Group By O_Id
    Having Count(Distinct OrderPrice) > 1 )
```